# Crash upon getting data from NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, selector, nsuserdefaults

Getting data from NSUSerDefaults and Passing has parameter application get crashed

```
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [loginController showView:[prefs objectForKey:kSavedUserName] :[prefs objectForKey:kSavedUserPassword]];
//              [loginController showView:@"abcd03@gmail.com" Password:@"apple”];
```

When i am printing those value in NSLog `[prefs objectForKey:kSavedUserPassword]` is showing value. password and `[prefs objectForKey:kSavedUserName]` user name.

If I hard-coded  my requirement parameters it working fine.

My crash log is

```
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5ccc2d0
2011-07-21 14:32:27.721 iShop[3815:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LoginViewController showView::]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5ccc2d0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
```

Comment: If the code you have given here is the same you are using, check the method call. You will find your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `loginController` doesn't respond to the `showView::` message, that's why your app crashes. Check the method name in `LoginViewController`, and correct it. I think there is no matter with `NSUserDefaults`.
Also try to avoid unamed parameters in selectors, **always** name them, to avoid problems.

Answer (score 1):

Your commented out code is correct in that it has a name for the second parameter.

```
[loginController showView:@"abcd03@gmail.com" Password:@"apple”];
```

Where your example with NSUserDefaults omits 'Password' from the selector. Try changing it to

```
[loginController showView:[prefs objectForKey:kSavedUserName] Password:[prefs objectForKey:kSavedUserPassword]];
```

On a more stylistic point I would suggest changing the method name to something more like below.

```
showViewForUserName:(NSString*)user_name password:(NSString*)password;
```

Comment: a more conventional is : `showViewForUserName:(NSString*)user_name password:(NSString*)password;`.

Comment: Updated my example to match the convention.